# Cannot Load the Database in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I'm following the tutorial of loading a dvdrental database as shown in the link below:
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/

I have done the first step successfully but when I came to the step 2 and 3 which navigating the bin folder and loading the data I was stuck.  It keeps prompt me with the invalid command message as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: Hy, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You should be running [`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) from the shell, not from inside [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html). `pg_restore` is a separate command line program, not a `psql` command.

Comment: what meant..hmm..means that how should I type in the command window

Comment: You're still inside `psql` prompt when you type `pg_restore -U ...`, you need to run that from a normal command line prompt.

Comment: hmm how can I run it from a normal command line prompt...sorry I'm totally new to this software

Comment: Open a terminal window or console or cmd.exe window and type the `pg_restore` command from there.

Comment: it came out with invalid command..sigh..I'm confusing sql shell and psql

Comment: I dont know what "invalid command" means or who is saying that. Start by opening a plain old command prompt and then fix your `PATH` environment variable or use the full path to `pg_restore`.

Comment: I wish I could find the link on that page to even download the sample dvdrental db, apparently it is not there anymore.

Comment: @OutOFTouch: Yeah, they say "download the file at this link:" but there's no link. Maybe [this thing on github](https://github.com/robconery/pg-dvdrental) is what you're looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

yes i have one solution
check the your file path and before that extract the file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just type `exit`.

Your are actually inside psql server and are executing command you should execute on windows.

Typing `exit` will close the psql connection and put you back on the windows terminal